# ChromeDriverManager().install() FileNotFound Error

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

chrome_driver = ChromeDriverManager().install()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_driver)

driver.get("https://www.amazon.com")
```

I'm installing chrome driver using ChromeDriverManager and I got 'FileNotFound' Error.

Here is my error terminal:

```
<Error Code>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\dongh\PycharmProjects\day-48\main.py", line 5, in <module>
    chrome_driver = ChromeDriverManager().install()
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\dongh\PycharmProjects\day-48\venv\Lib\site-packages\webdriver_manager\chrome.py", line 40, in install
    driver_path = self._get_driver_binary_path(self.driver)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\dongh\PycharmProjects\day-48\venv\Lib\site-packages\webdriver_manager\core\manager.py", line 35, in _get_driver_binary_path
    binary_path = self._cache_manager.find_driver(driver)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\dongh\PycharmProjects\day-48\venv\Lib\site-packages\webdriver_manager\core\driver_cache.py", line 101, in find_driver
    browser_version = self._os_system_manager.get_browser_version_from_os(browser_type)
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\dongh\PycharmProjects\day-48\venv\Lib\site-packages\webdriver_manager\core\os_manager.py", line 78, in get_browser_version_from_os
    OSType.WIN: windows_browser_apps_to_cmd(
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\dongh\PycharmProjects\day-48\venv\Lib\site-packages\webdriver_manager\core\utils.py", line 28, in windows_browser_apps_to_cmd
    powershell = determine_powershell()
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\dongh\PycharmProjects\day-48\venv\Lib\site-packages\webdriver_manager\core\utils.py", line 54, in determine_powershell
    with subprocess.Popen(
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\dongh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\subprocess.py", line 1024, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Users\dongh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\subprocess.py", line 1509, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] Specified path not found
```

I tried to install chrome driver and I got 'FileNotFound' Error.
Why does this happen?

Comment: use this - driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())

Comment: I think the issue here relates to Chrome 115.xxx and availability (or otherwise) of a compatible driver

Answer (score 1):

You may try this way:

```py
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))

driver.get("https://www.amazon.com")
```

references:

- [i can't open any link from vs code by webdriver_manager.chrome module with ChromeDriverManager class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76544187/i-cant-open-any-link-from-vs-code-by-webdriver-manager-chrome-module-with-chrom/76545583#76545583)
- [Chromedriver version 115 not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76762892/chromedriver-version-115-not-found/76763525#76763525)
- [Purpose of webdriver manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76453996/purpose-of-webdriver-manager/76454059#76454059)
- https://pypi.org/project/webdriver-manager/

Answer (score 0):

If you are using latest version of selenium (at least `v4.6.0` or above), you don't need a third party library like `WebDriverManager` to handle and manage browsers and browser drivers. Your code can be as simple as:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.amazon.com")
```

Reference - https://stackoverflow.com/a/76463081/7598774