# Python Selenium - NoSuchDriverException: Unable to obtain chromedriver using Selenium Manager

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Getting the following error when trying to create object with Selenium Webdriver:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchDriverException: Message: Unable to obtain chromedriver using Selenium Manager; Message: Unsuccessful command executed: Z:\Python 3.9.0\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\windows\selenium-manager.exe --browser chrome --output json.
```

The same script work with one pc and get the error above with another.

The script is:

```
service = Service()
dimensione_finestra = 'start-maximized'
url = '...'
opzioni_chrome = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
opzioni_chrome.add_argument(dimensione_finestra)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=opzioni_chrome)
driver.get(url)
```

Any idea?

Comment: Check this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/76463081/7598774

Answer (score 0):

You may try using the `Service()` class along with `ChromeDriverManager().install()`

```py
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome, ChromeOptions
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

options = ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")

driver = Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)
driver.get("Url")
```

and you'll need to install

```
pip install selenium
pip install webdriver-manager
```

reference:

- [ChromeDriverManager().install() FileNotFound Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76785179/chromedrivermanager-install-filenotfound-error/76785395#76785395)

Comment: Thanks, it doesn't work but the error is more specific, it seems a firewall problem